# Clone Row in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, prepend

I am trying to copy a div and prepend it to the beginning of the parent div. This is my code... i cant figure out the problem?

```js
//Ad row 
function addRow(btn) {

  var CopiedRow = $(this).closest('.itemRow').clone(true);
  $(this).parent().prepend(CopiedRow);

}
```

```html
<div class="show_hide" style="display: none;">
  <hr />
  <div class="form-group itemRow">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="add_qty[]" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Beschreibung der auszuführenden Arbeit!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      ***********************
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 nopadding">
      <select class="form-control input-sm s2_basic">
        <option class="text-muted" value="#" selected>****************</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="col-md-1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addRow(this);"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>



</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You're calling `addRow` from an `onclick` attribute, passing in the clicked button element as an argument.

   But you're not *using* the argument in `addRow`, you're using `this` instead. If you used your `btn` argument, the code would work. It would also work if you hooked up the function using modern event technicals rather than `onclick`, because then `this` *would* refer to the button being clicked.
2. You're using `.closest` to try to find `.itemRow`, but `.itemRow` isn't an *ancestor* element of the button, it's a sibling. You could use `.prev()` with your current structure.

So either use `btn` (and `prev`):

```js
//Ad row 
function addRow(btn) {
  var CopiedRow = $(btn).prev().clone(true);
  $(btn).parent().prepend(CopiedRow);

}
```

```html
<div class="show_hide">
  <hr />
  <div class="form-group itemRow">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="add_qty[]" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Beschreibung der auszuführenden Arbeit!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      ***********************
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 nopadding">
      <select class="form-control input-sm s2_basic">
        <option class="text-muted" value="#" selected>****************</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="col-md-1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addRow(this);"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>click me</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or ditch the `onclick` and use modern event hookups (and `.prev`):

```js
$(".addrow").on("click", function() {
  var CopiedRow = $(this).prev().clone(true);
  $(this).parent().prepend(CopiedRow);
});
```

```html
<div class="show_hide">
  <hr />
  <div class="form-group itemRow">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="add_qty[]" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Beschreibung der auszuführenden Arbeit!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      ***********************
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 nopadding">
      <select class="form-control input-sm s2_basic">
        <option class="text-muted" value="#" selected>****************</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="col-md-1 addrow" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>click me</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues :

1) Your clickable element is not inside `<div class="form-group itemRow">...</div>`, therefore `$(this).closest('.itemRow')` will be an empty jQuery collection. Try moving the clickable element inside the `.itemRow` div.

2) `function addRow(btn) {...}` is passed `this` (the clickable element), which becomes `btn` inside the function ..... but you don't use `this`. With the button inside the `.itemRow` div, try :

```
function addRow(btn) {
    $(btn).closest('.itemRow').clone(true).prependTo($(btn).closest(".show_hide"));
}
```